# Rspec request.env wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, rspec-rails

This is my code:

```
before(:each) do
  request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(api_key.access_token)
end
```

My test was supposed to pass but it is displaying this error:

```
Failure/Error: request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials("#{api_key.access_token}")
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
```

- Gems:

  rspec-rails version = 2.14.1.

  rails verison = 4

  mongoid from 'git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'

Comment: Where is api_key set?

Comment: let(:api_key){ ApiKey.create}

Comment: the "let" comes first in the code

Comment: Does calling ApiKey.create work? Try api_key = ApiKey.create within the before each block and see if that's what's throwing the error

Comment: The error persists! :(

Comment: Api_key variable created within the before each block has the value which it was expected to have.

Another fact is that I'm able to "login" with token by curling:  curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/applications -H 'Authorization: Token token="mytoken"'

Comment: Can you try this in your rails console? ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials("anything"). does it throw an error?

Comment: It returns: "Token token=\"anything\""

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Post your full error message by running rspec with the --backtrace option

Comment: I don't know if it will help but, I'm using the rails-api gem to build my api.

Comment: When I try this: 
    `post url, { "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(api_key.access_token)}` rspec does not raise the error. However, the test still not being able to "login" yet.

Comment: I tried to print:  `last_request["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(api_key.access_token)` and worked...

Comment: I would print out `method(:request)` and `request.method(:env)` at the line you are getting the error to make sure you're invoking the `request` method you think you are.

Comment: When I print `request.method(:env)` I get this error: `Failure/Error: print request.method(:env)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)`

Comment: But when I print `method(:request)` I get this result: `#<Method: RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1(Rack::Test::Methods)#request>`

Comment: I'm using Rack::Test::Methods on my spec_helper(`config.include Rack::Test::Methods`)...

Answer (score 2):

The `request` method you are accessing in your test is documented at http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack-test/0.6.2/Rack/Test/Session:request and expects 1 or 2 arguments as the error indicates. You're getting an error on `request.env` because you're invoking `request` with no arguments.

Comment: I`ll implement it later.

Comment: @FelippeDaMottaRaposo I'm curious, how did you end up implementing this?

Comment: Sorry but I really don't remember.
I stop working in this project 3 years ago!
:/